# Footer out of alignment on zoom in / zoom out

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having a problem with a website's footer.

When working on it at 100% size (normal size) the footer is nicely aligned. However, when I resize it it goes totally out of alignment and sits to the left, it needs to stay centred.

**Screen shot:**

[image: Footer misalignment]

**Relevant CSS:**

```
/* Dark blue area above the main part of the footer, stays aligned */
#footerUpper {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #252B76;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 30px;
/*  padding: 5px;*/
}

#footerUpper ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 25px 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#footerUpper li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 52px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#footerUpper li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Main part of the footer */
#footer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #252B76;
    background-color: #89B0F1;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* Table within the footer */
#footerTable {
    width: 980px;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're floating your footer?

Comment: @F4r-20 No, it must have been left in because of something else; commenting it out doesn't help however. It's still got the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing more of the code, or a working example of it it's difficult to get too much of an idea about what's going wrong.

But I think a solution might be to have a static width on the inner-content, so for example the content that is mis-aligning itself, which I think is your "footerTable" - apply "margin:0 auto" to it to centre align it, this is assuming it's parent is 100% width, which I believe it is. Also, remove any other margin rules that apply to it.

Comment: This has pretty much got it. I've taken the `float: left;` off the footer and put `margin: 0 auto;` on the table, it seems to be fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're floating the footer to the left, and then there's no container of the footer which is centrally aligned. You can either:

- Remove `float: left` and instead do a `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`
- Make a container for your footer (or preferably your entire layout if it's all to be centrally aligned) and align the container to the center using `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`

There are of course other ways to centrally align block elements, but these are the most effective and recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no reason to be floating the footer (so you say):

Remove the following styles:

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

Then, to make sure the table is centered, add this style:

```
text-align:center;
```

And you should find the footer stretches to the page width, no matter what zoom.